# amsalpha-like bibtex style with manual labels

Tags: bibtex

I want to do `amsalpha` style citation with BibTeX, except that I want to have manual control over the key/labels (e.g., `[ABC09]`). Is there an option for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you give a small example, with a sample of a bib entry and what you really need to do?

Answer (score 7):

One of the optional fields of a BibTeX entry is `key` which is used for put in alphabetical order, cross-references and as label when the `author` or `editor` information is not available. Thus one can use the `key` field for the value of records for which one wants to manually control the label.

To this end one has to modify the `amsalpha.bst`, in particular the `FUNCTION {output.bibitem}`. (Please create a copy of `amsalpha.bst` and change the name to it, let us say `myamsalpha.bst`) This function can be modified as follows

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[" write$
  key empty$
    {label write$}
    {key write$}
  if$
  "]{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

Then, you can use it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{first,
  author = "Last, First",
  title = "First Title",
  journal = "Journal Name",
  year = 2012
}
@Article{second,
  key = {ABC12},
  author = "Last, First",
  title = "Second Title",
  journal = "Journal Name",
  year = 2011
}
@Article{third,
  author = "More, First",
  title = "Third Title",
  journal = "Journal Name",
  year = 2011
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Testing citations
\cite{first} 
\cite{second}
\cite{third}

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

While Guido's solution was quite helpful to me, it resulted in incorrect sorting of the bibliography. To have consistent sorting it is better to only modify the `calc.label` function in the custom bibtex style (e.g. `myamsalpha.bst`) as follows.

```
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ key empty$
  { type$ "book" =
    type$ "inbook" =
    or
      'author.editor.key.label
      { type$ "proceedings" =
          'editor.key.organization.label
          { type$ "manual" =
              'author.key.organization.label
              'author.key.label
            if$
          }
        if$
      }
    if$
    duplicate$
    year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #2 substring$
    *
    'label :=
    year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$
    *
    sortify 'sort.label :=
  }
  { key 'label :=
    key sortify 'sort.label :=
  }
  if$
}
```

This will yield in addition to the custom labels also the correct sorting of the labels in the bibliography. However I must admit that using this solution the user is responsible himself for avoiding duplicate keys.