# Customize some (but not all) of the citation keys that appear in the text body?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I'm writing up my PhD thesis and am using `natbib` (I'm not married to `natbib` and can switch if I have to).  My question is about customizing what I'll call the *citation keys*, by this I mean the text that the reader sees in the main body, and which refers the reader to an entry in the bibliography.

In most cases I want this to behave as it usually does in `natbib`.  However, when I'm referring to my own papers, I want to use customized citation keys to make it easier for the reader to distinguish my papers from each other.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8428/use-bibtex-key-as-the-cite-key) is similar, but in that cases they're customizing *all* of the citation keys, which I don't want to do.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) From your mail I understand that you are using a BibTeX bibliography file. Could you add examples of references you now get and what you would like to see.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91423/21591, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102/21591

Comment: For using the `key` field as a custom label, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73491/21591.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Feel free to close this question as a duplicate of that one.