# Why is the style file mdpi.bst not working properly in Word (using bibtex4word plugin)?

Tags: bibtex, msword, custom-bib, bbl

I'm using the plugin [bibtex4word](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/perl/b4w_using.html#Quick) in `Word 2013` to insert citations & bibliographies. When I try styles **plain, IEEEtran** etc., they look exactly as they're described. But when I try a new style file: **mdpi.bst** downloaded from [here](http://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex), the **label**s look strange in Word:
[image: mdpi citation & bibliography]

The label style should be numeric like "`[N]`" as described and it works fine with `LaTeX`:
[image]

I've searched and read some posts, still with no clues what to do:

1. [What should I change in a bst file in order to have numbered entries in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141003/what-should-i-change-in-a-bst-file-in-order-to-have-numbered-entries-in-the-bibl)
2. [amsalpha-like bibtex style with manual labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73463/amsalpha-like-bibtex-style-with-manual-labels)

Question is: What's wrong with the bibtex4word plugin or Word or the mdpi.bst style file? How can I fix that?

### PS1:

The `bbl` file auto generated by bibtex4word seems to be ok:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{-------}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}

\bibitem[Feng \em{et~al.}(2014)Feng, Taguchi, and Kamat]{feng_fast_2014}
Feng, C.; Taguchi, Y.; Kamat, V.R.
\newblock Fast plane extraction in organized point clouds using agglomerative
  hierarchical clustering.
\newblock  2014 {IEEE} {International} {Conference} on {Robotics} and
  {Automation} ({ICRA}),  2014, pp. 6218--6225.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use style flag 'n'. Provide the style format like this: 'MDPI/n' in Set Style box of Add-ins.